# Questions about computing the commutator of the Lorentz generator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator

I am computing the commutator of the Lorentz generators, from the Eqn (3.16) to Eqn (3.17) in Peskin & Schroeder.
$$
\begin{aligned}
J^{\mu\nu} &= i(x^\mu \partial^\nu - x^\nu \partial^\mu ) &(3.16)\\
[J^{\mu\nu}, J^{\rho\sigma}] &= i (g^{\nu\rho}J^{\mu\sigma} - g^{\mu\rho}J^{\nu\sigma} - g^{\nu\sigma}J^{\mu\rho} + g^{\mu\sigma}J^{\nu\rho}) &(3.17)
\end{aligned}
$$

However, my answer differs from Eqn (3.17) by a factor of $i$, as I pulled out of the factors of both terms in the commutator and got $-1$ instead of $i$. I wonder where it went wrong here?

Also, when computing it, I had:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&x^\mu \partial^\nu(x^\rho \partial^\sigma)\\
=& x^\mu \partial^\nu x^\rho \partial^\sigma + x^\mu x^\rho \partial^\nu \partial^\sigma \\
=& g^{\nu\rho}x^\mu\partial^\sigma + 0,
\end{aligned}
$$
where I assumed the second term is zero. But I don't have a solid proof why $x^\mu x^\rho \partial^\nu \partial^\sigma = 0$.

Comment: If the second term is zero, why is $J^{\mu\nu}$ itself not also zero?

Comment: These are operators, they are hungry to *act* on something (some function $f(x)$ in your case). So: $x^\mu \partial^\nu( x^\rho \partial ^\sigma f(x))=\ldots$. At the end of your calculation, you write your result again without the dummy function $f(x)$.

Comment: @Hyperon Thanks. But I don't think this is why my answer was wrong. I computed that $[x^\mu \partial^\nu, x^\rho \partial^\sigma]$. Say, adding the dummy function, it would be $([x^\mu \partial^\nu, x^\rho \partial^\sigma])f(x)$. All calculations happens before applying to that function. What I meant here is $x^\mu \partial^\nu$ acting on $x^\rho \partial^\sigma$.

Comment: @Oбжорoв I thought that was the two partial differentiations that makes the term zero. But I just reviewed my calculations. Those terms involving $\partial^\mu \partial^nu$'s cancels out if assuming $x^\mu$'s and $\partial^\mu$'s commute with themselves. But I'm not sure if this is always true.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the *operator relation* $x^\mu \partial^\nu x^\rho \partial^\sigma = x^\mu g^{\nu \rho} \partial^\sigma + x^\mu x^\rho \partial^\nu \partial^\sigma$? Good that you don't have a "solid proof" for $x^\mu x^\rho \partial^\nu \partial^\sigma=0$, because this is simply *wrong*. As you should also know, $[x^\mu ,\partial^\nu]= -g^{\mu \nu}$.

Comment: @Hyperon I got the second term by product rule, and wasn't aware of the commutator relation between $x^\mu$ and $\partial^\nu$. The metric tensor in my equation comes from $\partial^\nu x^\rho = \partial^\nu g^{\alpha\rho} x_\alpha = g^{\alpha\rho} \partial^\nu x_\alpha =  g^{\alpha\rho} \delta^\nu_\alpha$.

Comment: Concerning the first question, note that $J^{\mu \nu}$ is defined with a pre-factor of $i$.  So to get the commutator in terms of $J^{\mu \nu}$, you need to keep one of the $i$'s around, rather than combining them to get a factor of $-1$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Say, we define a operator $A^{\mu\nu}$ such that $J^{\mu\nu}= i A^{\mu\nu}$. Then, $[iA^{\mu\nu}, iA^{\rho\sigma}] = (iA^{\mu\nu})(iA^{\rho\sigma}) - \cdots$. This involves a factor of $-1$. Or just by the bi-linearity of the commutator, we would have a factor of $-1$.

Comment: Right, but in terms of $A^{\mu \nu}$ we have $$[iA^{\mu\nu}, iA^{\rho\sigma}] = g^{\nu\rho} (i J^{\mu\sigma}) - g^{\mu\rho}(iJ^{\nu\sigma}) - g^{\nu\sigma}(iJ^{\mu\rho}) + g^{\mu\sigma}(iJ^{\nu\rho}) = g^{\nu\rho}A^{\mu\sigma} - g^{\mu\rho}A^{\nu\sigma} - g^{\nu\sigma}A^{\mu\rho} + g^{\mu\sigma}A^{\nu\rho}$$ and there's still no real problem with a stray factor of $i$.